# How can I load class nelmiocorsbundle in symfony 4.2

Tags: symfony, nelmiocorsbundle

I have installed NelmioCorsBundle with composer require nelmio/cors-bundle but when i send a request i have the below error:

> Attempted to load class "NelmioCorsBundle" from namespace "App\Nelmio\CorsBundle"
>
> Did you forget a "use" statement for "Nelmio\CorsBundle\NelmioCorsBundle"?

Comment: can you post your bundles.php ? edit : whoops wrong filename

Answer (score 0):

You should have the following line in your `config/bundles.php`:

```
Nelmio\CorsBundle\NelmioCorsBundle::class => ['all' => true]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\DoctrineCacheBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Nelmio\CorsBundle\NelmioCorsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Snc\RedisBundle\SncRedisBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```